# True or false statement? Every linear mapping $f: V \rightarrow W$ with $Ker(f)=0$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

True or false statement? Every linear mapping $f: V \rightarrow W$ with $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ is injective.

I think that $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ is just one of several conditions to be injective. We also need a good matrix size where the rows $\geq$ columns. This statement doesn't consider this and thus it's false?

Comment: What happens if $v\neq w$ and $f(v)=f(w)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linearity of $f$ and $\ker(f)=0$ are sufficient conditions. In fact:

$f(v)=f(w)\implies f(v)-f(w)=0$, and by linearity of $f$ we have $f(v-w)=0$. Now, using the fact that $\ker(f)=0$ we have $v-w=0\implies v=w$

Note that I didn't use anything else to prove the statement, thus it is true, because $f$ is just a general map which satisfy the two hypothesis written above.

Comment: Does that mean the statement is true, even though it's saying "every"?

Comment: Editing to make it clearer

Comment: Oh I forgot something, actual task says $\text{dim Ker(f)}$ and not just $\text{Ker(f)}$. But nothing will change right? Tyvm for your answer btw.

Comment: @kathelk: You can note that the dimension of a space is $0$ if and only if it is $\{0\}$.